# Gitlab job to run ONLY ONCE when Merge Request is created

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want some specific jobs in my pipeline run only one time when I create a Merge Request. For example to assign reviewer for the MR, or to migrate data from QA environment.

Is there a way to achieve this in Gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate ? By default, all jobs are ran only one time. Are you talking about conditional runs ?

If so, I think the `only/except` concepts could be of interest. Maybe by using `only:variables/except:variables`. You would have to reimplement some logic in the background depending on your use case, though not so complicated (set a boolean at true/false).

See [the doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) for `only/except`

Comment: I mean the job should run only one time when I create the MR, after that it won't run any more when the pipeline is triggered